# Django import export can't import MultiSelectField Checkbox

Tags: python, django, checkbox, import, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export in an app of my web project.

The **class.py** file is as:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    siret = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    newspaper = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    TOPIC_TYPE = (
            ('Sport', 'Sport'),
            ('Beauté','Beauté'),
            ('Food', 'Food'),
            ('Business', 'Business'),
            ('Music', 'Music'),
            ('Art', 'Art'),)
    topics = MultiSelectField(choices = TOPIC_TYPE)
```

Note that *topics* is a MultiSelectField.
In **admin.py** I simply followed the django-import-export tutorial, hence:

```
class ArticleResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ('is_true', )

class ArticleAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ArticleResource

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

The issue while importing data is as you guess with the "topics" variable.
I first exported an xlsx file to see the way this variable is exported. This is literally how:

```
siret             ...      topics
-----------------------------------
0000068591590     ...      Music, Art
0000068591595     ...      Business, Beauté
0000068591600     ...      Art
```

The issue, is with data importing.
I simply tried to import back the above exported file, by changing "siret" numbers.
Once imported, in the admin interface, I was surprised, Django laughed at me by selecting only the first topic for each article in the available CheckBoxes (only Music for 0000068591590, only Business for 0000068591595).

[image]

Hence I tried to import through:
Music, Art  (as exporting way)
['Music','Art']
[Music, Art]

However It's not working.
Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing an excel file, be careful about spaces...
Django *exports* like

```
siret             ...      topics
-----------------------------------
0000068591590     ...      Music, Art
0000068591595     ...      Business, Beauté
0000068591600     ...      Art
```

Note the spaces in the topics variable.
You just have to *import* multi select choices like:

```
siret             ...      topics
-----------------------------------
0000068591590     ...      Music,Art
0000068591595     ...      Business,Beauté
0000068591600     ...      Art
```